# Arabic text stemming

Tags: arabic, stemming

hello i wrote a small program using java to remove some prefix from an Arabic text 
this is a part of it

```
 while(fip1.hasNext())
                {
                   String s1=fip1.next();

                    if (s1.startsWith("ال")) 
                       {s2= s1.substring(2);}
                    else if (s1.startsWith("وال"))
                        {s2= s1.substring(3);}
                    else if (s1.startsWith("بال"))
```

the problem is that when i got to result i noticed that any first word in the line did not processed

i think fip1.next start with the second word

any help
 thanks

Comment: What is the type of `fip1`?